# Getting the name/id of the select that was changed

Tags: jquery

All,
I have the following select:

```
<select name="options_1" id="options_1" class="select_me"> 
    <option>1</option> 
    <option>2</option>  
</select>
```

I have multiple selects with the same class on my page. When I change one of these selects I'd like to get the name or ID of the select and then the value that is after the underscore.

Can anyone let me know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("SELECT[id^=options]").bind('change', function() {
       var fullId = $(this).attr('id');
       var idParts = fullId.split('_');
//       idParts[0] would be options
//       idParts[1] would be 1
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use class as selector for change() handler

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/QjEkS/

```
$('select.select_me').change(function(){
   var id=this.id;
   var num_val= id.split('_').pop();
    alert( 'ID: '+id +', Num: '+num_val);    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.select_me').on('change', function(){
   var id = this.id,  // original id
       number =  id.substr( id.indexOf('_') + 1 ); // numeric part of id
});
```

**[Working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/QjEkS/1/)**